# Passing a variable from aspx to .cs

Tags: button, sender, commandargument, aspbutton

I am trying to pass an Id from aspx to .cs.  This is the code i have in the aspx:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddAsFriend" runat="server" Text="Add as Friend" onclick="btnAddAsFriend_Click" CommandName = "Id" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("u.UserID.ToString()") %>'/>
```

The CommandArgument is being set but when i try to read it from the .cs its getting null.  This is the code I have in the .cs

```
 protected void btnAddAsFriend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: need to pass value from clientside to server side ..is that what you meant?

Comment: it's still getting empty in the server side do i have to set any page propeties?